# how do I get data from html table in a grid format in python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get a table from an exchange's web page so I can play with it. Ideally looking for some sort of Matrix variable (dataframe??) to make it easy to play with.
However, so far I am stuck with parsing the html table itself. Heres' the code....

```
from lxml import etree
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests

SYMBOL = "NIFTY"

URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch  /option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbol=" + SYMBOL + "&date=-"
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

req =Request(url=URL, headers=headers)
Opt_Page = urlopen(req).read()
#print(Opt_Page)
html = etree.HTML(Opt_Page)

tr_nodes = html.xpath('//table[@id="octable"]/tr')
tmp = tr_nodes[0].xpath("th") #herein begins the problem.
# this give totally blank output.. tried with node[0] to [20]
print(tmp) 

## 'th' is inside first 'tr'
header = [i[1].text for i in tr_nodes[1].xpath("th")]
td_content = [[td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')] for tr in tr_nodes[1:]]

print(header)     # all headers are empty
print(td_content) # all content is empty
```

expect the row headers and individual row contents as output...

Comment: Have you looked at [pandas read_html()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)? Quite nice for taking web tables and ingesting them into a nice format

Comment: I dont know what your ultimate goal is, Excel/Google Spreadsheets have built-in importxml/ImportHtml functions that might come handy.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the `pandas` library `pip install pandas`, as well as the relevant dependencies (probably `pip install lxml`), then use a DataFrame:

```py
from pandas import read_html

html = """
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""
tables = read_html(html)
df = tables[0]

print(df)
print('----------')
print(df['Last'][0])

# Prints the following:
# 
#   First   Last
# 0  John  Smith
# 1  Jane    Doe
# ----------
# Smith
```

For more help with using pandas `DataFrame`s, check out the tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe/) or the official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).